# MVC isn't adding Content-Length for stuff it gzips

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a controller returning dynamically generated JS code in a `JavaScriptResult` (ActionResult).

```
    public ActionResult Merchant(int id)
    {
        var js = "<script>alert('bleh')</script>"; // really retrieved from custom storage
        return JavaScript(js); // same as new JavaScriptResult() { Script = js };
    }
```

The default gzip filter is compressing it but not setting `Content-Length`. Instead, it just sets `Transport-Mode: Chunked` and leaves it at that.

```
Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity:True
Cache-Control:public, max-age=600
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 06 Nov 2015 22:25:17 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Timing-Allow-Origin:*
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

How can I get it to add the header? I absolutely *need* this header. Without `Content-Length`, there's no way to tell if the file completed downloading, e.g. if the connection dropped. Without it, some CDNs like Amazon CloudFront aren't able to properly cache.

After turning off compression, I get a normal Content-Length. It seems trivial for the gzip filter to add this length - there must be an option somewhere?